# Xhr upload progress event not working in firefox under ubuntu

Tags: javascript, firefox, ubuntu, xmlhttprequest, progress

The following code works fine in chrome under windows and linux (Ubuntu) but firefox works under windows and not Linux (Ubuntu) :

the progress fires once after upload completes !

```
$.ajax({
   type: POST,
   url: "upload.php",
   data: [formdata object],
   dataType: "json",
   xhr: function() {
        var progressXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if(progressXhr.upload){
            progressXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false);
        }
        return progressXhr;
   },
   beforeSend: function(jqXHR){
    $("#upload_div").show();
   },
   complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
    $("#upload_div").hide();
   }
});

function progressHandlingFunction(e){
    percent = (e.loaded * 100) / e.total;
    $("#upload_div").html("%" + percent);
}
```

Comment: it is a firefox bug in ubuntu. i couldn't find a workaround yet !!!